# JavaScript Object prototype function not available as expected

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

If you open [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beardtwizzle/4JCxb/embedded/result/), you should see in Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools that an exception is thrown when `x.method` is called, as `method` does not exist.

However if you run either `Object.method` or `Function.method` in the console you'll see that they do indeed exist in their respective prototypes.

I'm sure its a simply inheritence issue, but its beyond me at this point as to why the `method` method isn't bubbling up to the `x` Object.

The code is as follows:

```
// Crockford's Object.create shim
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

// Add a method creation function to the Function prototype
// Note that on this line I've also tried:
// Object.prototype.method = Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) { 
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

// Create our object
var x = Object.create({});

// Add common methods to the prototype of our new object
x.method('logNumber', function (num) {
    console.log(num);
});

// Try it out
x.logNumber(6);
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure if I understand what you're trying to do. But I think `this.prototype[name] = func;` doesn't do what you think it does. `this.prototype` is not the prototype that `this` inherits methods and properties from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**note**] jsfiddle seems to be down at the moment, so I couldn't check your code

This function:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

adds a method to the *Function prototype*. An Object is created using a constructor function: a function that, called with the `new` keyword, will create instances of the Object it constructs. In the `Object.create` 'shim' the constructor function is `F`, but the shim returns *an instance* of it (`new F()`).

Variable `x` is *not a constructor Function*, but *an instance*. You can only call `method`  from Function.prototype, so `x.method` is `undefined`.

*Not* using `Object.create` may show you how it works:

```
function X(){}; //=> new X will create an instance of an empty Object
X.method('logNumber', function (num) {
     console.log(num);
});             //=> call 'method' from the constructor: now it's working
var x = new X;  //=> create an instance
x.logNumber(6); //=> behold!
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but does not have a console

```
Object.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this[name] = func;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jhBjs/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that instead of `this.prototype[name] = func` you want `this[name] = func`.  Also I'm guessing you want this on Object:

```
Object.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.[name] = func
    return this
}
```

Given that you're already using Crockford's object thingy, you can do the following, if you don't need this for all `Object`s:

```
var X = { method: function (name, func) {
    this[name] = func
    return this
}

var x = Object.create(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

var x, x is an Object, not a function, that is why you need to use

```
Object.prototype.method = function (name, func) {    
  this[name] = func;    
  return this;
};
```

Comment: // Note that on this line I've also tried:
// Object.prototype.method = Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {

Comment: @beardwizzle: this line will give error: `this.prototype[name] = func;`                                                           `this` point the instance object which has no `prototype` property.